# PowerShell - Search for email addresses and exclude some addresses

Tags: regex, powershell

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\failed log' -Recurse |
  Select-String -AllMatches '\w+@\w+\.\w+' |
  Select-String -NotMatch '\w+@repoinfotec.\w+'| 
  Select-Object FileName
```

**Explanantion**
Above pipeline finds all email IDs excluding @repoinfotec.com

**Problem**
It should find all the email addresses excluding @repoinfotec.com and @bnymellon.com, so how to exclude 2?
Should I put them in for loop or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet here, just pass the `-Path` to the `Select-String` cmdlet. To exclude two domain names, use the regex or `|`:

```
select-string -Path 'your_file' -Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+' | 
    where Line -NotMatch '\w+@(repoinfotec|bnymellon).\w+'
```